# ElasticSearch Delete bulk items

Tags: javascript, curl, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-bulk-api

I'd like to delete all the documents of a certain type.

But this only works on versions 1.0 and higher:

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/index/type/_query?pretty' -d 
'{
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                {
                    "match_all" : {} 
                } 
            ] 
        } 
    }
}'
```

I tried this on ES v1.4.x and it works fine. It's when I run in on ES v0.90.13 where it fails. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation looks like for elasticsearch verserion 0.90x the [delete by query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/docs-delete-by-query.html#docs-delete-by-query) should not be nested in  query term :

i.e the above query should be as follows :

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/index/type/_query?pretty' -d 
'{
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                {
                    "match_all" : {} 
                } 
            ] 
        } 
  }'
```

However for version 1.X  documentation does mention that for [delete by query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/docs-delete-by-query.html#docs-delete-by-query) the query  should be nested inside a query similar to search api.

This is mentioned in the breaking changes of [1.0 release](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_search_requests.html)